# Accessing Tomcat Status from the Command-Line

Tags: tomcat

I am looking for a simple REST API that will provide the status of the various web application that are deployed in a Tomcat container.

The information I'm looking for is easily obtained by pointing your browser at:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

This shows the web applications that are loaded, and whether each web app is running or stopped.

I would like to access this same information using "curl" from the command line.  It is not a problem to hard-code the Tomcat username/password credentials in the curl command-line, as this is a secure server where no one has an active account.  Is there a REST API that would allow me to do this easily?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manager webapp has the `/text` URL too and it has many options.  For example, a simple list of the applications:

```
$ curl -u tomcat:tomcat http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list
OK - Listed applications for virtual host [localhost]
/:running:0:ROOT
/examples:running:0:examples
/host-manager:running:0:host-manager
/servlet_example_war:running:0:servlet_example_war
/manager:running:1:manager
/docs:running:0:docs
```

Note that you need to add additional roles to Tomcat (often in `conf/tomcat-users.xml`) to use the "text" commands.  See [Configuring Manager Application Access](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) first for the roles you need to add and then [Supported Manager Commands](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands) for all of the things you can do with the text portion of the manager web app.

Comment: Ok this looks like what I need so I will try it out.  I notice you did not pass any credentials in your curl command, aren't credentials needed?  Oh wait nevermind, I guess the username/password is tomcate:tomcat.... duh.  Sorry